# How to disable the auto-focus in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iPhone application, i am using UIImagePickerController to capture the image.

```
UIImagePickerController  *mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaPicker.delegate=self;
mediaPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

Here i need to disable the auto focus option available in UIImagePickerController. Can anyone provide the solution to accomplish the above problem.

Comment: answers on that question doesn't helps me.